# what was debug loggind and text provider?

Tags: python, performance, window, game-development, chrome-app-developer-tool

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class SpartanApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return Label(text="this is spartaa!!!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SpartanApp().run()
```

Output:

```
[CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```